# J1 visa two year exemption rule

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, tax-exemption

I have been granted a fellowship for a postdoctoral position at a university in the USA starting from September 2023 and with two years duration. The fellowship is from a non-profit European foundation (**foreign-sourced fellowship**).

Please note that in 2022, I was as a visiting Ph.D. student at the same university for some months with a **J1 student visa**. During my visit, I didn't receive any US income - my visit was paid from another European scholarship at that time. In April 2023 I filled out the 8843 form for exempting the days as a J1 student visa holder.

As a postdoc fellow, I will have a **J1 visa (nonstudent)**. According to what I read on the IRS website, I cannot exclude a US day of presence as a 'teacher or trainee' for more than two calendar years. That is to say that I can exempt my presence in the US as a J1 visa holder during 2023 but not the following years (since I have been exempted in 2022 already).

However, my question is how shall I be treated for the years 2024 and 2025? I saw that **there is an exemption for teachers-trainees to the two-year rule** according to which:
"*you will be an exempt individual if you were exempt as a teacher, trainee, or student for any part of 3 (or fewer) of the 6 preceding calendar years and:

- A foreign employer paid all of your compensation during the current year.
- You were present in the United States as a teacher or trainee in any of the 6 prior years.
- A foreign employer paid all of your compensation during each of the preceding 6 years you were present in the United States as a teacher or trainee.*"

Do you think that I could claim that the foreign employer is the European foundation for my presence in the USA as a J1 visa holder in the year 2024? Which was also the employer for the year 2023.

Following this exception, I will not meet the Substantial Presence Test criteria and I may not be treated as a resident for tax purposes (it will be strange to pay US taxes given that I won't receive US income for the period being there).

Thanks in advance!

E.

Comment: Why don't you want to be treated as a resident? Do you have a lot of income outside the US unrelated to your work in the US? Why do you claim you won't have US income? Income from work performed while you are in the US is US income.

Comment: I do not want to be treated as a resident because then the fellowship is taxable. In Europe this fellowship is not tax liable as it comes from a foundation.

Comment: Will you still be a tax resident of the country you were resident of before coming to the US? Does that country have a tax treaty with the US?

Comment: Yes, I will be a tax resident of my country which has a tax treaty with the US.

Comment: Most US tax treaties have a section on residence, where if a person is a resident of both countries, then there is a process for determining which country you are a resident of. Perhaps this can allow you to be a nonresident in the US.